# enhance combobox expanding speed

Tags: wpf, performance, user-interface, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox with 3000 items. It takes several seconds to expand it. Is there a way to expand it faster? The items are bound using ItemsSource and a binding path:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeItems}" />
```

Comment: here's some combobox code for [UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the virtualization stackpanel to improve the performance. In this case just changing the ItemsPanel's ItemspanelTemplate from StackPanel to VirtualizingStackpanel won't do any magic, because when you press the downbutton the data is loaded in the Popup. so you have to modify the StackPanel inside the ScrollViewer to VirtualizingStackpanel. To do that Edit the ControlTemplate/Style for the combobox using Expression blend or VS and change the control templates Popup area like below

```
<Popup
Name="Popup"
Placement="Bottom"
IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Focusable="False"
PopupAnimation="Slide">
<Grid
  Name="DropDown"
  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
  <Border
    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
    BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
  <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>  </Popup>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is an overkill :)